# How can I send multiple e-mails, to multiple recipients using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim MItem As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim email_ As String
    Dim cc_ As String
    Dim subject_ As String
    Dim body_ As String
    Dim attach_ As String
    Dim StrBody As String

     'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     'Loop through the rows
    For Each cell In Sheets("publico").Range("H2:H2000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If cell.Row <> 1 Then

            If cell.Value <> "" Then     ' to check email address cell is empty or not
                email_ = cell.Value      ' email address mention in the F column
            Else
                email_ = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'alternative email address
            End If
            subject_ = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D1").Value    'as of now i mentioned column B as subject, change the value accordingly
           ' body_ = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D2").Value       'please change the offset value based on the body content cell
            StrBody = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D2").Value & "<br><br>" & _
            Sheets("CAPA").Range("D3").Value & "<br><br>" & _
            Sheets("CAPA").Range("F7").Value & "<br><br><br>"
            **Sheets("publico").Range**
           ' cc_ = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value       ' remove comments if you are going to use the cc and also change the offset value according to cc mail address cell value.
           ' attach_ = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value   ' remove comments "'" if you going attache any file and change the offset value based on the attachment value position.

             'Create Mail Item and send it
            Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With MItem
                .To = email_
               ' .CC = cc_
                .Subject = subject_
                .HTMLBody = StrBody
                '.Attachments.Add attach_
                '.Display
            End With
            MItem.Send
            Sheets("publico").Range("J2").Value = "enviado"
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

So, for branch 100, manager 15, I will send line 1 and 2 of the sheet, to the manager mail only.

In the case of no manager assigned, the email will be directed to the head (email2).

After sending an e-mail, the F column must generate a log "OK".

EDIT:

I edited the code provided and the e-mail is going to the proper recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim MItem As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim email_ As String
    Dim cc_ As String
    Dim subject_ As String
    Dim body_ As String
    Dim attach_ As String

     'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     'Loop through the rows
    For Each cell In Columns("f").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If cell.Row <> 1 Then
            If cell.Value <> "" Then     ' to check email address cell is empty or not
                email_ = cell.Value      'email address mention in the F column
            Else
                email_ = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'alternative email address
            End If
            subject_ = cell.Offset(0, -4).Value  'as of now i mentioned column B as subject, change the value accordingly
            body_ = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value      'please change the offset value based on the body content cell
           ' cc_ = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value       ' remove comments if you are going to use the cc and also change the offset value according to cc mail address cell value.
           ' attach_ = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value   ' remove comments "'" if you going attache any file and change the offset value based on the attachment value position.



             'Create Mail Item and send it
            Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With MItem
                .To = email_
               ' .CC = cc_
                .Subject = subject_
                .Body = body_
                '.Attachments.Add attach_
                '.Display
            End With
            MItem.Send
            cell.Value = "ok"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Hi Arun.

After some editing, I've managed to use nearly all of your code, and it works neatly. Thank you very much.

I've edited the original thread with some minor doubts. Think you can help me?